# Difference between Copyright License (CLA) Copyright Assignment (CAA)

Tags: copyright, contributor-agreements

I have just wrote a program and would like to release it dual-license (probably AGPL and proprietary, but I also would like to retain the ability to release it under other licenses in the future).

I want to welcome patches from the future community, but merging should not compromise the goal above, so if I understand correctly I need a kind of contributor agreement.

The [Harmony Agreement Selector](http://selector.harmonyagreements.org/) looks like a tool designed for me, but I am stuck at the first question:

[image: Harmony Agreement Selector]

As seen in the screenshot above, there are two options:

- Copyright License (CLA)
- Copyright Assignment (CAA)

What is the difference between the two?